# mysql database auto_id wrongly arranged in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I don't have any coding related problem. I've a small doubt here related to mysql database. Below i've attached an image. I've inserted some records into database. For example totally 40 records i've inserted into mysql database. Some records deleted by the users. Problem is if i insert a new record (auto id is 41) its insert a record into middle of the another two rows. You can see my image below three row is there (7, 41 and 40). Why 41st record is inserted between 7 & 40 ? Why 41st record not inserted after 40th id?

[image: Database image]

Comment: actually, it doesn't matter at all. When you select the records,just order them properly using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin to view above ?

Comment: @dev yes.. phpmyadmin

Comment: @今草顿웃: when i fetch the datas from mysql db i faced a little bit problem (wrongly fetch) because of this..

Comment: because in phpmyadmin data always displayed in order to last inserted last.if you want to see data in sorted order just click on sort icon near id.

Comment: Read Mike W's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't guarantee and order unless you specifically ask for one with an `ORDER BY` clause. If you want your rows in `VoucherID` order specify `ORDER BY VoucherID` in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * from MyTable ORDER BY VoucherID
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems its related to sorting at your phpmyadmin view. just click on column header of "VoucherID" and check than. currently it seems sorted with "VoucherReference" (descending)